# Lebesgue Integration - Dominated Convergence Theorem [Exercise]

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm not really sure of what I did in order to prove the convergence of an integral around zero.
I have $f_n: (0,+\infty)\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ $$f_n = \frac{1}{xe^{n/x}\log(1+nx)} $$
and after proving that $f_n$ is measurable for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$, I say that: $$ \mathcal{U}(0)   
\space\space\space f_n \sim \frac{1}{n^2x^3e^{n/x}}\leq c\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\space$$
Where $c \in \Bbb{R}$ is a constant and since $c\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \in L'(\mathcal{U}(0)),$ I've finished saying that $f_n \in L'(\mathcal{U}(0))$, but I'm not really sure if I can use
asymptotic and after that the upper bound.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: What does $U(0)$ mean? Is it a neighborhood of $0$? What about $L'$?

Comment: Since $f_n$ is a decreasing sequence of positive functions, it is sufficient to check that $f_1$ is Lebesgue integrable. In that way you don't have to deal with $n$.

Comment: @ydx yes i mean a neighborhood of zero with that notation and L' is the set of all the function f such that the Lebesgue integral of f is finite.